# How do I analyse JVM crash?

Tags: java, crash, jvm, jvm-crash

A Java Web application that I am running has been crashing every 30 days or so with the following error:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000005ebf568, pid=8360, tid=5688
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_55-b13) (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.55-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# J  org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies.process(Lorg/apache/http/HttpRequest;Lorg/apache/http/protocol/HttpContext;)V
#
# Core dump written. Default location: D:\Program Files (x86)\WebAPp\WebManagement\bin\hs_err_pid8360.mdmp
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

What steps do I need to follow to understand what might have caused this crash?

Comment: Try upgrading to the latest version of Java 7 to see if the problem has already been fixed. You're running 7u55, and latest public update is [7u80](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html).

Comment: Thanks, are you suggesting that the cause of the crash could be because of Java and not because of the application?

Comment: Definitely. Java should never crash. It should be impossible to write any Java code that causes the JVM to crash like that. Only if you write C code and call it from Java, should you be able to crash the JVM process, because the JVM cannot protect against bad C code. Unless `RequestAddCookies.process(...)` is a `native` method implemented in C, that JVM crash shouldn't have been possible.

Comment: BTW Java 7 is EOL, Java 8 and 9 are about to be end of public updates. You might want to update to a never JVM, possibly Java 10.